# Creating fishnet along linear feature in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I want to create square grid of polygons along a polyline(Road). Assigning spatial extent of the polyline will create grid squares not containing the line as well.

Do I have any other options ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this I think you should try the [Grid Index Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/grid-index-features.htm) tool which:

> Creates a grid of rectangular polygon features that can be used as an
>   index to specify pages for a map book using Data Driven Pages. A grid
>   can be created that only includes polygon features that intersect
>   another feature layer.
>
> ...
>
> **Input Features** can be points, lines, polygons, or rasters.

Answer (score -1):

You can split your feature line in equal parts by using split in the editor toolbar, and choosing the length (example 100 meters) of the future segments from this process. After this, u can directly apply buffer where u can set the distance around each of segments

Comment: A buffer will not create a the desired grid. Instead it will create a round buffer a round buffer with a fixed distance around each of the segments.